# Is $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ two-dimensional or three-dimensional?

Tags: linear-algebra

I was reading Mathematics for Economists by Simon and Blume.

> The level set $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ is a two-dimensional sphere of radius $1$.

How to actually know that it is two dimensional?

Comment: How do you define $2$-dimensional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it is a surface, namely a sphere. Also we can see that we can change two variables arbitrarily, say $x$ and $y$ and then $z$ changes accordingly. We cant arbitrarily change all three variables. This means there are two degrees of freedom.

Comment: Thank you so much for giving me the intuitions for viewing dimensions.

Comment: No problem, glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

It is probably easier if we look at in terms of spherical coordinates:
$$x = \sin(\theta) \cos(\phi), y = \sin(\theta) \sin(\phi) \text{ and } z = \cos(\theta)$$
Note that $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$.
We only have two degrees of freedom, namely, $\theta$ and $\phi$. Hence, it is a two dimensional surface.

Answer (score 0):

Every point of the sphere has a neighbourhood that looks like $\mathbb{R}^2$ (If we are talking about dimension as a manifold).